# Communicating between databases Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, rabbitmq, zeromq

I have two rails servers running. One is dedicated towards handling the login part of the applicating and other one is handling the data associated with rest of the application. For some reason, the login database is not meant to be integrated with the main application database.

However I need to keep the track of the data associated with a particular user which requires communication between databases.RabbitMQ or ZeroMQ might help but I haven't quite figured out yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MYsql you can use CAS https://github.com/intinno/ruby-cas-server to authenticate from centralize server. might it help in other database as well.

Comment: Thanks Amitkumar Jha.But my database engine is PostGreSQL.

Comment: Hey Ruby-cas support for postgres as well. I used in one of my project

Comment: Adopting a different method now. Anyways I will try.